# Simple AngularJS controller for REST API

Tags: javascript, angular.js, promise, rest

We record software builds from our build machine into a database and for practice purposes I'm building a little web dashboard for it.

The API is REST (WebApi) and provides access to query for Products, Branches, Profiles and specific Builds.

The controller queries all products (each product contains a list of branches and profiles it has been build for) as well as all branches and profiles anything was ever built for.

It then goes on to query the last 10 builds for each of the branches and profiles a product was built for.

This is my first attempt at anything related to web-programming so I thought I'll get someone to look at it. Here is the code:

```
(function (angular) {
    var app = angular.module("app", ["ngResource"]);

    app.factory("Product", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
        return $resource("/api/Product");
    }]);

    app.factory("Build", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
        return $resource("/api/Build");
    }]);

    app.factory("BasicResource", ["$q", "$http", function ($q, $http) {
        var resourceFactory = {
            async: function(type) {
                var d = $q.defer();
                var result = $http.get("/api/" + type).success(function() {
                    d.resolve(result);
                });
                return d.promise;
            }
        };
        return resourceFactory;
    }]);

    app.controller("MainCtrl", ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$q", "$http", "BasicResource", "Product", "Build", function ($rootScope, $scope, $q, $http, BasicResource, Product, Build) {
        $rootScope.title = "Build Dashboard";
        $scope.Builds = [];

        $q.all([
            Product.query().$promise,
            BasicResource.async("Branch"),
            BasicResource.async("Profile")
        ]).then(function(data) {
            $scope.Products = data[0];
            $scope.Branches = data[1].data;
            $scope.Profiles = data[2].data;
        }).then(function() {

            var allBuildQueries = [];
            $scope.Products.forEach(function (prod) {
                prod.branches.forEach(function(b) {
                    prod.profiles.forEach(function(prof) {
                        allBuildQueries.push(Build.query({ product: prod.name, branch: b, profile: prof, limit: 10 }).$promise);
                    });
                });
            });

            $q.all(allBuildQueries).then(function (allBuilds) {
                allBuilds.forEach(function(builds) {
                    builds.forEach(function(build) {
                        $scope.Builds.push(build);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }]);

})(angular);
```

There are a few things which I don't really like about it so far but don't know how to improve it:

1. The `/api/Branch` and `/api/Profile` resources return a list of strings. This causes [the issue described in the SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813673/one-dimensional-array-of-strings-being-parsed-to-2d-by-angular-resource). The two basic workarounds are to use `$http` or transform the response. I have used `$http` because it seemed the easiest and I have not figured out how to use `transformResponse` properly so far (documentation on that is somewhat light). However it results in the factories (`Branch` and `Profile` vs `Product` and `Build`) having slightly different interfaces which bugs me.
2. The second issue is the async query of the builds. Currently it queries `Number of Branches` x `Number of Profiles` per product for all products. At the moment this results in about 90 queries and really is no problem. However I'm wondering how this should be done properly in case the number of queries can grow into the hundreds or thousands.
3. <strike>The way how I combine all the build query results seems somewhat inelegant to me. In C# I'd use a LINQ query like `allBuilds.SelectMany(x => x.builds).ToList()`. Would strike me as weird if there wouldn't be a more elegant javascript way of doing it.</strike>

   Since asking the question I have started using [linqjs](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) so that solves this issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use this `unexplodeWord` function:

   ```
    var explodedWords = [{"0":"h","1":"e","2":"l","3":"l","4":"o"},    
                          {"0":"w","1":"o","2":"r","3":"l","4":"d"}]

    var words = explodedWords.map(unexplodeWord);

    // Converts {"0":"h","1":"e"} to "he".
    function unexplodeWord(explodedWord) {
      var chars = [];
      angular.forEach(explodedWord, function(char) { 
        chars.push(char);
      });
      return chars.join('');
    }

    words.forEach(function(item) { console.log("word: " + JSON.stringify(item)); });
   ```

   You would call it as such:

   ```
       $scope.Products = data[0];
       $scope.Branches = data[1].map(unexplodeWord);
       $scope.Profiles = data[2].map(unexplodeWord);
   ```

   You would still have some asymmetry relative to Products, but not as much.
2. If I understand correctly, you want some kind of advice about pagination.  If you really get too much data, maybe you could print only the branches and profiles for one product at a time.

   If you have too many branches and profiles for a single product, you should probably only output either branches or profiles, and paginate those.

Comment: For 1) that looks like an acceptable compromise. For 2) No I don't particularly look for pagination advise. My concern is that I issue one query per product-branch-profile - and these are all issued in parallel (and the waited on through the promises). Out in the wild (the internet) I'd probably kill my backend server fairly quickly with that so I'm interested what better solutions would exist.

Answer (score 2):

Your "BasicResource" resource factory can be greatly simplified:

before:

```
app.factory("BasicResource", ["$q", "$http", function ($q, $http) {
    var resourceFactory = {
        async: function(type) {
            var d = $q.defer();
            var result = $http.get("/api/" + type).success(function() {
                d.resolve(result);
            });
            return d.promise;
        }
    };
    return resourceFactory;
}]);
```

after:

```
app.factory("basicResource", ["$http", function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function(type) {
            return $http.get("/api/" + type)
                .then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    };
}]);
```

You don't need to call the method `async` because consumers will expect a promise from such a method. Also resource is probably not the best name for a service which only provides get functionality.

Regarding response transformation, there are several ways to do it. Per request, or by registering interceptors with `$httpProvider`.

Personally, my preference is to avoid `$resource` entirely as it behaves oddly, transforming a promise into its result for example. `$http` meets my needs.

Also note that `.success` and `.error` are deprecated and you should use `.then` and `.catch` in their place. This will improve interop and avoid some quirks.